# Export OpenLayers as shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, shapefile, tab

Is it possible to save an OpenLayers map as a shape or tab file in QGIS. I would like to have a part of an area from Google Maps as a shapefile for later use?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps in the openlayers plugin are 256x256px tiles, so you can not easily export them as vector data into a shapefile.

What you can try is make a screen copy of the current view with `File -> Save as Image`, load that as a raster layer, transform that into vector, and save that as shapefile.

Comment: screen copy will geocoded?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't use a print screen. Instead use File>>Save as Image. This will save an image, and a world file, which should give the image a spatial location.

Comment: hmm, I need it to be geocoded. A shame it is not easy done.

Comment: geocoded? It's a raster image.

Comment: Google Maps have geocoding information in their API, but you can not get that from the Openlayers plugin in QGIS. You may need a license (and some programming skills) to use their API.

Comment: The image is not Geocoded...